# A question about SOS duality

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np

Let us start with the optimization question,

\begin{eqnarray*}
min \{ c \vert c - f \in SOS_d \}
\end{eqnarray*}

for some function $f : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $SOS_d $ being the cone of all polynomials on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which can be written as a sum of squares of polynomials each of degree at most $\frac{d}{2}$. This can be cast as a SDP by doing the "gram matrix" rewriting of any polynomial in $SOS_d$.

- Now how do we show that the above is dual with no duality gap to this following optimization question?

\begin{eqnarray*} 
&max_D \{ \tilde{\mathbb{E}}_D [f] \} \\
&s.t \\
&D : \{ 0,1\} ^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
&\sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} D(x) = 1 \\
& \forall u \in SOS_d \\ 
&\tilde{\mathbb{E}}_D [u] \geq 0 
\end{eqnarray*}

where for any function $g : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}_D [g] := \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} D(x)g(x)$

---

I tried writing a conic duality for the first to get it to look like an optimization over Lasserre maps but that approach didn't work...

Comment: Talking to some professors I figured out why the later should be a conic dual of the former but I still don't know why the duality gap should be $0$. Any reference explaining this would be very helpful!